# App Distribution with App Clip - Required Capabilities

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to distribute a new version of my app to app store connect with an app clip. The info.plist for my app and for my app clip have the same required device capabilities:

```
<array>
    <string>location-services</string>
    <string>gps</string>
    <string>armv7</string>
    <string>arkit</string>
</array>
```

I am getting the following error when trying to distribute the app:

```
Invalid required device capabilities.
The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities values [arkit, location-services, gps] in the Info.plist of app clip 'GrifGraf.app/AppClips/grifgrafAppClip.app' must match the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities values [arkit, location-services, gps] in the Info.plist of the app.
Match the device capabilities between your app and app clip.
With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90845 for id
```

I've double checked that the capabilities match between the two plists, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

I deleted the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array from the info.plist in both my app and app clip, and built the app to my phone. Xcode's debugger errored saying that the app clip's required device capabilities needed to match the main app's capabilities, and included multiple capabilities in the error message, including location-services.

This means it's not looking at my info.plist files...

I grepped for location services in the project root, and found that project.pbxproj was the only spot that contained the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array containing location-services so it got it from there. project.pbxproj is actually hidden inside of your .xcodeproj package, you have to show package contents to access it.

I deleted the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array from that file, and then re-added the device capabilities to both my app and the app clip's info property lists and it resolved the issue. My guess is, it's looking inside that file to determine what the required device capabilities are, and it was out of sync with my info.plist files.